# Angular JS: Why am I not able to send data through `$http`?

Tags: javascript, web-services, angularjs, http

In my controller, I am sending an `http` request through the following:

```
var postData = { action: 'getTasksByProjectSlug', slug: 'inbox' }

$http({
    url: 'http://localhost/toodloo/api/kernel.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: postData,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
}).success(function( data, status, headers, config ){
    console.log( data );
}).error(function( data, status, headers, config ) {
    console.log( status );
});
```

and in `kernel.php` I have got the following:

```
class Kernel
{
    function __construct( $requestData )
    {
        if ( ( isset( $requestData ) === false ) || empty( $requestData ) ) {
            die( 'No data received!' );
        }

        $this->findRoute( $requestData );
    }

    public function findRoute( $requestData ) {
        ...
        } else if ( ( $requestData['action'] === 'getTasksByProjectSlug' ) && isset( $requestData['slug'] ) ) {
            $this->getTasksByProjectSlug( $requestData['slug'] );
        } else {
        ...
    }

    public function getTasksByProjectSlug( $slug ) {
        $project = new Project;
        $tasks = $project->getTasksByProjectSlug( $slug );

        $json = json_encode( $tasks );
        echo $json;

        return $json;
    }
}

$kernel = new Kernel( $_POST );
```

Now the problem is all that is returned by `console.log( data );` inside the `success` of the `$http` is `'No data received'` and that is what API does when the condition `( isset( $_POST ) === false ) || empty( $_POST ) )`, so what I infer from this is request is being sent to the server but the data `var postData = { action: 'getTasksByProjectSlug', slug: 'inbox' }` that I am sending along with it is somehow not received on the server side.

Can anyone please tell me what I might be doing wrong here? Why is `postData` not being sent on the server side?

P.S: I have also tried with `data: JSON.stringify(postData)` but the results were still the same

Comment: did you check jsfiddle or network console at your browser ?

Comment: You can try to convert your data to url encoded string. jQuery have $.param just for that.

Comment: @jcubic I've already tried that but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following at the top of `Kernel` class instantiation, worked for me:

```
$requestParams = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$requestParams = (array) $requestParams;
```

Now the `$requestParams` was behaving just like `$_POST`.